# R ggplot date breaks in x axis

Tags: r

Hi all and apologies if this came up but I could not find 100% match answer to my question...

I have a csv file named zed made of 3 cols and 366 observation: 
`FTD_DAY, FTD_DATE, FTD` imported in `R`. 
`FTD_DATE` looks like a date (dd/mm/yyy) but `R` reads it as integer (`typeof(zed$FTD_DATE)` displays `integer` in `GUID`).

I then geom_point the data using:

`x <-ggplot(data=zed, aes(x=FTD_DATE,y=FTD))` and the x axis looks ugly since cannot fit 366 dates making it unreadable.

Questions I have:

1. How can I order dates in x in ascending order?
2. How can I break coordinates showing only (say) 7 coords maintaining all 366 observations?
3. How can I align the dates in x axis vertically?

I tried `scale_discrete()`, `scale_log()` etc. but went nowhere or got somewhere in the wrong place... can someone please help and let me know what is the solution using `ggplot`?

Comment: Take a look at `scale_x_date`, `scales::pretty_breaks(n = 7)` & `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1.0))`

Comment: Hi Tung, thanks for your input. I tried scale_x_date() but it gave me Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only (perhaps it has to do with FTD_DATE typeof = integer?). I could not find documentation over scales::pretty_breaks.. is it an argument of scale_x_date? In any case I am trying different options but cannot get to the solution. I will keep trying but any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to use as.Date(FTD_DATE ,format = "%d/%m/%Y").  R has to be told this is a datetime data.

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput()`? See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: str(zed)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
$ FTD_DAY : Factor w/ 7 levels "FRI","MON","SAT",..: 7 1 1 7 1
$ FTD_DATE: Factor w/ 366 levels "01/01/2018","01/02/2018",..: 47 323 187 154 19
$ FTD     : int  301 315 251 303 218 

Summary(zed)
FTD_DAY       FTD_DATE      FTD  
 FRI:3   02/06/2017:1   Min.   :218.0 
 MON:0   04/10/2017:1   1st Qu.:251.0 
 SAT:0   13/09/2017:1   Median :301.0 
 SUN:0   16/06/2017:1   Mean   :277.6 
 THU:0   27/10/2017:1   3rd Qu.:303.0 
 TUE:0   01/01/2018:0   Max.   :315.0 
 WED:2   (Other)   :0  .......would the above summary and str be useful?

Comment: Hi, after further attempts I managed to spread the coordinates neatly in the x axis converting FTD_DATE col. using: zed$FTD_DATE <- as.Date(zed$FTD_DATE,format = "%d/%m/%Y"). The new problem is that the dates are now showed as integers in the x axis (0000,0010,0020, etc.)...When I use the typeof(FTD_DATE) function I get "double" whilst it used to be "integer". Basically FTD_DATE is still a read as a number and displayed wrongly in the x axis.. How can I finally make it look like what is supposed to be? A date? Anyone could help? Thanks... A